# Create Nuget package from .NET framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to create nuget package from class library that targeting .NET framework 4.0

So

1. I download `nuget.exe`
2. Open cmd console
3. Create lib folder in root
4. Build project and copy dll's from `root/bin/Release` to `root/lib/net4` folder
5. Use  `nuget spec CRM_Mailer.csproj`

Folder structure:

```
- root
   -- lib
     -- net4
        -- CRM_Mailer.dll               
        -- Cryptography.dll  
        -- DataConnector.dll  
        -- CRM_Mailer.csproj

nuget pack CRM_Mailer.nuspec
```

6. Fill my CRM_Mailer.nuspec

   ```
    <package>
        <metadata>
            <id>CRM_Mailer</id>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
            <title>Test1</title>
            <authors>testUser</authors>
            <owners>testUser</owners>
            <!-- <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl> -->
            <!-- <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl> -->
            <!-- <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl> -->
            <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
            <description>hope it's work</description>
            <releaseNotes>Realy hope</releaseNotes>
            <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
            <tags>Win32</tags>
            <references>
                <reference file="CRM_Mailer.dll" />  
                <reference file="Cryptography.dll" />      
                <reference file="DataConnector.dll" />
            </references>
        </metadata>
    </package>
   ```
7. Use `nuget pack CRM_Mailer.nuspec` and get these warnings:

   > WARNING: NU5100: The assembly 'bin\Release\CRM_Mailer.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.
   > WARNING: NU5100: The assembly 'bin\Release\Cryptography.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.
   > WARNING: NU5100: The assembly 'bin\Release\DataConnector.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.
   > WARNING: NU5100: The assembly 'obj\Debug\CRM_Mailer.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.
   > WARNING: NU5100: The assembly 'obj\Release\CRM_Mailer.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.
8. `nuget add  CRM_Mailer.0.0.3.nupkg -Source C:\GIT\NugetPackages\NugetPackageCreator\Package`
9. Package is working

The questions are:

- Why do I get warnings in step 7 - and how to a void them?
- Why spec doesn't copy information from assembly.info ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu5100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your file stucture  solution is simple.

Just remove 'obj' and 'bin' folders before  executing `nuget pack` command

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies downloaded via nuget should be located in "Lib" folder (as the warning says, and not on root folder). To fix it, copy assemblies into sub-folder "lib" and change spec file to point to assemblies:

`<reference file="Lib\{file}">`

Comment: dll are in the lib folder , as I said in the step 3